# What does ">" in this jQuery selector mean?

Tags: jquery, css

What difference does the greater than symbol (`>`) make here?

Is `$('#someElement').find(">[someAttribute]")` the same as `$('#someElement').find("[someAttribute]")`?

Comment: FIRST search Google, then look up the jquery doucmentation and then (if you don't know another way) ask!

Comment: sorry my very very bad english :)

Comment: Not a bad question at all! upvotes for the answer proves that.

Answer (score 17):

No : it only selects an element if it's a direct child of `#someElement`.

It's semantically based on the CSS direct child selector.

See [child selector's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)